# Does Ashenzari's Skill Boost effect your skill aptitude?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

I have been playing Ashenzari as a Fire elementilst and have I have 4 piety and all slots bounds (including all three Jewelry items). When I press m to look at my skills, none of my aptitudes have been increased. Does it just increase the total (not the aptitude)? Is there a way to see how much it is being boosted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ashenzari's skill boost adds to your current skill values - sort of the opposite of Draining.  I'm not sure what the interface is in ascii view, but in tiles, you can see your effective skill values by mousing over each skill - the number displayed on the skill box itself will be the level the skill is trained to (rounded down), but the more precise value displayed when you mouse over it will include the boost.

If you need more precise information than that, you can do the math yourself:

```
The exact formula is: min(piety_rank, bondage_level + 2) * factor - skill_level / 4
Factor = 1 for a low level of bonus, 1.25 for a medium, and 1.5 for high)
```

Source: http://crawl.chaosforge.org/index.php?title=Ashenzari

The bonus is added to your skill level - the amount of experience it would take you to gain the next level of the skill isn't a factor.